# How to deal with changing variance in data sets

Tags: descriptive-statistics, signal-processing, spectral-analysis, astronomy

I've done an entry level stats course, so my knowledge is very limited in regards to this topic. I'm dealing with large datasets (~3000-9000 data points), and trying to pick signals out of the noise for analysis. Here are two examples to illustrate my issue:

[image: Spectrophotometric data of NGC 6543][image: Spectrophotometric data of NGC 6058]

The first contains less noise, so I'm a little less concerned, but many of the datasets I'm using are like the second one, and have increased noise on the ends. In both, there are clear signals that I can filter out, but in the second one there are sharp increases in noise at either end of my data. Looking for those signals by simply taking the standard deviation of the entire set (sans clear outliers) would lead to signals in the center being obscured by the increased noise on the ends, and lead noise to be seen as signals. What can I do to find signals in data sets like this?

Comment: Can you say more about the kind of data you are working with, & your situation / task / goals? (Eg, you certainly do not seem to be working with signal detection theory.)

Comment: I'm pretty new to applying statistics, so I'm very likely to be using terms wrong. My apologies. I'm working with spectrophotometric data of planetary nebulae, and trying to find emission lines that I can match to the presence of chemical species in the regions being observed. My goal is to find the points in my data where the values of the relative intensities (y axis) of light at certain wavelengths (x axis) rises far enough above the noise to clearly constitute a signal.

Comment: chemometricians have been working a lot with kinds of spectral data, so maybe ask some? Or look through the [tag:chemometrics]

Comment: There are standard ways to solve this problem depending on the application.  For instance, such spectra are often *matched* against a "library" of basic spectra after various forms of preprocessing suggested by the physical and statistical properties of the measurement system.  In other cases peaks have to be differentiated from the noise in a purely statistical fashion, without reference to a library, but even then physical theory often plays a role.  For instance, Compton backscattering can be identified and subtracted from gamma spectra.  Consult the relevant literature.

Answer (score 0):

Tsay http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html suggests a two-pronged approach to deal with outliers and variance changes. A quick review of your data suggests multiple points in time where the error variance might change significantly.

Comment: FWIW, these are not time series: they are (visible light) *spectra.*

Comment: Tks .. If wavelength can be constrained to be equally spaced integers then this might be akin to "spatial data analysis" where auto-projective methods have  been employed ... But I am just speculating here ...